# Proper use of wp_get_object_terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

**Summary:**
How can I get the name and the permalink of the object returned by [wp_get_object_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)?

**Detailled:**
I created a custom post type called "ge_zielgruppe" and a taxonomy called "ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy". The latter can be attached to posts and to "ge_zielgruppe" post types.

On the single page of "ge_zielgruppe" I want to show the last few posts tagged with the same "ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy". I achieved this with

```
<?php
$theZielgruppe = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy');
$zielgruppe = new WP_Query(array('ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy' => $theZielgruppe->slug));
$zielgruppe->query('showposts=10');
if ($zielgruppe->have_posts()) :
    while ($zielgruppe->have_posts()) :
        $zielgruppe->the_post();
?>
<<--archive-stuff-->>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

This part works (however, I don't know if it's elegant).

Now I'd like to put a link right after these 10 posts, looking like this

```
<a href="<<--permalink to archive of 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy'-->>" rel="bookmark" title="More posts for <<--Name of 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy'-->>; ">More posts for <<--Name of 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy'-->></a>
```

So how do I get

1. `<<--permalink to archive of 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy'-->>`
   and
2. `<<--Name of 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy'-->>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the archive url for that taxonomy term, use something like this (I'm using your naming conventions above, and assuming that `$theZielgruppe` is a term object.

```
$url = get_term_link( $theZielgruppe, 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy' );
```

To get the name, just use

```
$theZielgruppe->name
```

Is that what you're looking for?

### EDIT

The link above would then look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $theZielgruppe, 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy' ); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="More posts for <?php echo $theZielgruppe->name; ?>; ">More posts for <?php echo $theZielgruppe->name; ?></a>
```

### EDIT 2

`wp_get_object_terms()` returns an array of terms. If you changed each use of `$theZielgruppe` to `$theZielgruppe[0]` to use the first term that the current `ge_zielgruppe` relates to. A warning, though: `wp_get_object_terms()` can return as either an empty array or as a `WP_Error`. You might want to change your code to check for that:

```
<?php
$theZielgruppe = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy');
if( !empty( $theZielgruppe ) && !is_wp_error( $theZielgruppe ) ):
    $theZielgruppe = $theZielgruppe[0];
    $zielgruppe = new WP_Query(array('ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy' => $theZielgruppe->slug));
    $zielgruppe->query('showposts=10');
    if ($zielgruppe->have_posts()) :
        while ($zielgruppe->have_posts()) :
            $zielgruppe->the_post();
    ?>
    <<--archive-stuff-->>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $theZielgruppe, 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy' ); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="More posts for <?php echo $theZielgruppe->name; ?>; ">More posts for <?php echo $theZielgruppe->name; ?></a>
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find get_term_link() yet, thanks for that. However $theZielgrupe->name doesn't work. Also <?php echo $theZielgruppe->name;?> leaves me without any output, although <?php print_r($theZielgruppe);?> works...

Comment: What does it say when you use `print_r($theZielgruppe);`?

Comment: output of print_r($theZielgruppe);: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 6 [name] => studierende [slug] => studierende [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 6 [taxonomy] => ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 ) ) please also note I updated my original question and added my call of wp_get_object_terms() in the first lines of the first code box.

Comment: Indeed. But what is that output?

Comment: Better question is how do you get `$theZielgruppe`?

Comment: $theZielgruppe = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'ge_zielgruppe_taxonomy');
 
I edited my original post to add an answer to this question (forgot this before)

Comment: great, that works! I tried both, using "[0]" and "-> name" before, but I never used them together! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to help out!